# How to prevent restarting fragment while screen rotation?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, android-viewpager

I have a webView fragment which i use in a viewPager.When i rotate the screen of my device the webview starts loading the webpage again.The fragment restarts when rotated.I dont want the webView to load again once loaded.How to avoid reloading in fragment while screen rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are generally three ways to do this:

1.As some of the answers suggested, you could distinguish the cases of your activity being created for the first time and being restored from savedInstanceState. This is done by overriding onSaveInstanceState and checking the parameter of onCreate.

2. You could lock the activity in one orientation by adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` (or `"landscape"`) to  in your manifest.
3. You could tell the system that you meant to handle screen changes for yourself by specifying android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in the  tag. This way the activity will not be recreated, but will receive a callback instead (which you can ignore as it's not useful for you).
   Personally I'd go with (3). Of course if locking the app to one of the orientations is fine with you, you can also go with (2).

Comment: Sir I understand your second option but the problem is I want to provide the user with more flexibility.But I don't understand your step 3.Can you explain it a bit more or provide a link to a tutorial?

Comment: Apparently using `orientation|screenSize` (?) prevents `onCreate` on Honeycomb and (so far) does not seem to break anything in previous Android versions.

    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

OnDestroy() will not be called anymore and your data will be kept.